# Android: Create an ENUM and insert a value for each key

Tags: android, enums, associative-array

I want to create an enum with keys from a database. Then for each key I want to set the value from the same database.

Because the database is extremely long.

For example the database could be filled with as such:

```
ABCD | 3
AAA  | Freddy
BB   | true
```

And will have a class like:

```
ENUM MyValues { ABCD, AAA, BB, ... }
```

And I could get a specific value:

```
MyValues.AAA //returns "Freddy"
```

(Hopefully the values can be any data type, but String will do if not possible.)

(I explored some articles that were too old.)

**How would I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use many types in enum. But if you want, you can try this:

```
public enum MyValues {
    ABCD(Integer.class, 3),
    AA(String.class, "Freddy"),
    BB(Boolean.class, true);

    private Object value;
    private Class<?> clazz;

    private MyValues(Class clazz, Object value) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getMyValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Class<?> getMyClass() {
        return this.clazz;
    }
}
```

Anyway, you have to parse the object to proper type!

Comment: This would allow any type - but I guess that isn't best, maybe should stick with Strings.  Again don't get caught-up with just those keys!  There are around 500 - I don't want to insert each.  Thus I want to create an enum on demand.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using @Liar answer. But it deviate from what the enum original purpose. You should stick to a single type of enum for the sake of code maintainability. Simply using a single type like this:

```
public enum MyValue {
  ABCD("3"),
  AA("Freddy"),
  BB("true");

  private String value;

  MyValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;  
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

where you can get the value by calling something like this:

```
ABCD.getValue();
```

Be aware that you can treat the Enum like a Class because **Enum is a class**.

When you're creating a data type class to represent a row of a table, you need to make the class describe the column value as it is or equally. For example, when your column is a string, you should use a string variable in your class instead of integer, double, or else.

Comment: Don't get caught-up with those keys!  There are around 500 - I don't want to insert each.  Thus I want to create an enum on demand.  Can this be done?